# Material Date Range Picker selection color formatting

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker, material-components-android, material-components

When you select two date in the range picker the in-between dates get highlighted. How do i change the color of the in-between dates?

[image: datepicker]

Comment: use this https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a style as:

```
  <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme_RangeFill" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/MyMaterialCalendar</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyMaterialCalendar"  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="rangeFillColor">@color/my_calendar_range</item>
  </style>
```

with this selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...."/>
</selector>
```

Then in your code:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builderRange =
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
builderRange.setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme_RangeFill);
```

[image]

If you want to change totally the color only in the `MaterialDatePicker` you can also use something like:

```
  <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme_RangeFill" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: what if I want to change the header color only ? how to do that? and if it is possible to change the size of the title "SELECT A DATE RANGE" ?

Comment: @RoohAl-mahaba Yes you can change them using the `materialCalendarHeaderLayout` and `materialCalendarHeaderTitle` attributes in your calendar theme overlay.

Comment: can you answer my question with examples please, I posted a question, thanks for your help

Comment: What is `materialCalendarHeaderLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the rangeFillColor to change the range selection active indicator color, but it doesn't work.
In the documentation it says it's the Primary container color but nothing happens when I try to override the color in the style.
Do you know if it still can be changed ?

The doc: https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/specs#89a4fb25-6806-45fa-92fb-bf8d71d5a2d1

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.CustomDatePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkPurple</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/lightPurple</item>
    <item name="rangeFillColor">@color/lightPurple</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just added

```
<style name="MyMaterialCalendar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialCalendar">
<item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/...</item>
    </style>
```

to change range color and it's worked fine with me